# How to create color Tiled Clone with Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, tiles

I followed [a tutorial](https://www.madera.k12.ca.us/cms/lib/CA01001210/Centricity/Domain/2631/Inkscape_07-RainbowAndClouds.pdf) and docs. What I have tried is

- Create a simple square Object.
- Select object and then Clone -> Create Tiles Clone
- Select Symmetry : simple translation.
- Set shift 10% per row, and per column.
- Color and other settings are as shown in below image.

That is not working as shown in tutorials. All created tiles are filled with black as parent.

I am using Inkscape on Windows 64

[image: Color tiled clone]

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: Image shown in question is different what I tried myself. Tutorial I followed is [here](https://www.madera.k12.ca.us/cms/lib/CA01001210/Centricity/Domain/2631/Inkscape_07-RainbowAndClouds.pdf) According to tutorial generated four squares should have filled with new color, regarding its position.

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to in your comment does work. I just tested it.

I suspect you have missed out the step that says you need to set the Stroke Paint to "Undefined".  The tutorial goes on to explain why:

> We need to do this because for changing colors of clones using clone
>   tool it is necessary that the paint is undefined for the object.

So, in the example you are trying to make, that would mean you'd need to instead set the Fill of the square to "Undefined", since it's the fill you want to recolour.

Here's an example which shows the original tutorial result, plus using the same technique for the squares, but instead setting the Fill to "Undefined", and then creating the tiled clones.

[image]

Comment: I missed to set "Undefined" for fill. Thanks.